# Updating Dart does not update Dart SDK to a more recent version

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

So I am currently developing an mobile application using Flutter and Android Studio. I have recently added a new package to my project (flutter_launcher_icons). I am on Windows. When I click on "pub get", the console prints this:

> "D:\Programmes Zip\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" --no-color pub get
> Running "flutter pub get" in apen_prototype...
> The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.1.
> Because apen_prototype depends on flutter_launcher_icons >=0.12.0 which requires SDK version >=2.18.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
>
> pub get failed (1; Because apen_prototype depends on flutter_launcher_icons >=0.12.0 which requires SDK version >=2.18.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
> Process finished with exit code 1

Obviously my version of the Dart SDK is outdated and I need to upgrade it. Well, here is my problem: I can't.
My Dart SDK seems to be in a Schrödinger state where, whenever I try to update it, it is already in the latest version (3.0.2), but when Android Studio wants to use it for pub get, it is outdated (2.17.1).

Here is what happens when I try the command `flutter upgrade` in Studio's terminal:

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.10.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9cd3d0d9ff (19 hours ago) • 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700
Engine • revision 90fa3ae28f
Tools • Dart 3.0.2 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

`dart --version` gives me a similar result:

`Dart SDK version: 3.0.2 (stable) (Tue May 23 08:26:58 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64"`

However, here is what I see in the settings of my project:
[My project's settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Kmz.png)

As you can see, the version is 2.17.1. Also note that the "check SDK update" button is greyed out. Modifying the path of the SDK lets me click the button, but then Android Studio only informs me that "Dart SDK 3.0.2 is available for [dowload](https://dart.dev/get-dart)", and does not actually download anything.

Now, obviously, I thought that the version of Dart SDK used in the Terminal was not the one actually embedded into Studio. So I used the command `(get-command dart).Path`, giving me the following result:
`D:\Programmes\flutter\bin\dart.bat`

So while the path of `dart` in the terminal is different from the path of the Dart SDK in settings, one is a sub-directory of the other, and the content of those directories is radically different, so it looks to me like these two paths are liked to the same installation of Dart SDK. I don't want to meddle with it without asking here first.

Here is how my pubspec.yaml file restrains flutter versions:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.1"
```

Whatever I do, I can't seem to update the Dart SDK... I am very tempted to just dowload it manually and just drag-and-drop it in flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk, but I am wondering if there isn't a more "clean" and "official" way of doing it...

Thank you for any help you can bring!

Comment: Increase the minimum dart sdk version in your pubspec.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think I've found some kind of solution.

Eventually I kinda got angry with that problem. I opened the [plugin window of Android Studio's settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fm4w.png)

I disabled both Dart and Flutter plugins, then re-enabled them and restarted Android Studio.
Well... as it happens, doing this finally updated the Dart SDK to the latest version. And I really mean the **latest** version, not a version corresponding with the constraints I described in my pubspec.yaml. Dart SDK was updated to 3.0.2, while the constraints in pubspec specified `>=2.18.0 <3.0.1`

Fortunately, my project is fully compatible with 3.0.2, so as far as I'm concerned, my problem is solved. I simply had to modify pubspec.yaml.
But I still have no idea how to force Android Studio to respect the constraints described in pubspec... I can only pray that this won't be a problem in the future...